# How to clang-format the current buffer on save?

Tags: clang

Whats the best way to clang-format a C/C++/GLSL a buffer on save, that does nothing in the case there is no clang-format file found for a project?

Answer (score 8):

Install the `clang-format` package and add the following hooks to your emacs init:

```el
(defun clang-format-save-hook-for-this-buffer ()
  "Create a buffer local save hook."
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook
            (lambda ()
              (when (locate-dominating-file "." ".clang-format")
                (clang-format-buffer))
              ;; Continue to save.
              nil)
            nil
            ;; Buffer local hook.
            t))

;; Run this for each mode you want to use the hook.
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (clang-format-save-hook-for-this-buffer)))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (clang-format-save-hook-for-this-buffer)))
(add-hook 'glsl-mode-hook (lambda () (clang-format-save-hook-for-this-buffer)))
```

---

Created [clang-format-on-save](https://codeberg.org/ideasman42/emacs-clang-format-on-save) package to make this into a minor mode.

Comment: For some reason this cases my file to be impossible to save even though it gets formatted.

Comment: Fixed, the function needed to evaluate to `nil`, also only run when `.clang-format` file is found.

Comment: Thanks for showing us `locate-dominating-file`. Would be helpful with `flycheck`, `lsp-mode`, etc. where the notion of a project is needed.

Comment: this answer is excellent, but is missing ')' on each of the last three lines.

Comment: @optimus_prime corrected (feel free to delete these comments to remove noise).

Answer (score 1):

Building on ideasman42's answer, I wanted to be able to turn this feature on an off, per buffer or globally.
Minor modes to the rescue :

```lisp
(use-package clang-format)
(defun clang-format-save-hook()
  "Create a buffer local save hook to apply `clang-format-buffer'"
  ;; Only format if .clang-format is found
  (when (locate-dominating-file "." ".clang-format")
    (clang-format-buffer))
  ;; Continue to save
  nil)

(define-minor-mode clang-format-on-save-mode
  "Buffer-local mode to enable/disable automated clang format on save"
  :lighter " ClangFormat"
  (if clang-format-on-save-mode
      (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'clang-format-save-hook nil t)
    (remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'clang-format-save-hook t)))

;; Create a globalized minor mode to
;;   - Auto enable the above mode only for C/C++, or glsl in your case
;;   - Be able to turn it off globally if needed
(define-globalized-minor-mode clang-format-auto-enable-mode clang-format-on-save-mode
  (lambda()(clang-format-on-save-mode t))
  :predicate '(c-mode c++-mode c-or-c++-mode))
(clang-format-auto-enable-mode t)
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case it may as well be a package, updated my answer to link to a package that implements the minor mode.