Clang Format on Save with format file in high up directory
Hello I have a series of projects that shares a clang format file.
With a basic folder structure similar to the below, each child folder contains its own subfolders and so.
- mommy/
  |- .clang-format
  |- child1
  |- child2

I want my files to be formatted by clang format on save.
How do I achieve this without using projectile to find the clang format file?
I tried following this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48503/12166
But it doesn't seem to take effect on save.
For instance the clang format file in the mommy directory states that { should not be on a line by it self, so a function like:
void test()
{
   std::cout << "main\n";  
}

Should be changed to:
void test() {
   std::cout << "main\n";  
}

Which visual studio code does as it is supposed to on safe with the same clang-format file, but Emacs does not. Emacs does not provide any errors nor warnings.

On MELPA there is the package clang-format which is easy to configure - only set clang-format-executable and set clang-format-stye to "file" - by default clang-format will load the style configuration from
a file named .clang-format located in one of the parent directories
of the buffer."

I have the clang format package installed. I update my question with a link to the option I am currently using.

Your question refers to /style/ formatting, rather than the mechanics of working with clang-format. See this page for info how to generate a .clang-format file and how further modify according to your needs. Some styles can be set from Emacs also.

@Ian no I can see that it does not take effect on save, because the code above does not change after save. So it is the mechanics of it I am asking for

How is generated your .clang-format file? open it and the first line will show the style. What you want is llvm style, while the first snippet is gnu style.

@Ian I know the file works as intended both Visual Studio Code and neovim formats correctly on save using the same file. Emacs just doesn't seem to apply it on save.

The problem here is your first snippet is really Alman style, not recognised  by Emacs (but by vscode, choosing Visual Studio file style).

What do you mean? It should adapt based on the clang-format file on save.

The solutions proposed in the link provided does not apply for you, due
to this lisp code line in lambda function, in both answers:
(when (locate-dominating-file "." ".clang-format")

This line means/force Emacs to look for .clang-format only in the
folder containing the edited file, or this is not what you want, so, clearly,
do not use those answers or the minor mode package suggested. Clang-format
can search for you that file. Try in your terminal the command clang-format --help
and see this:
  --style=<string>               - Set coding style. <string> can be:
                                   1. A preset: LLVM, GNU, Google, Chromium, Microsoft,
                                      Mozilla, WebKit.
                                   2. 'file' to load style configuration from a
                                      .clang-format file in one of the parent directories
                                      of the source file (for stdin, see --assume-filename).
                                      If no .clang-format file is found, falls back to
                                      --fallback-style.
                                      --style=file is the default.
                                   3. 'file:<format_file_path>' to explicitly specify
                                      the configuration file.
                                   4. "{key: value, ...}" to set specific parameters, e.g.:
                                      --style="{BasedOnStyle: llvm, IndentWidth: 8}"

You have two solutions to solve the problem:

if you are sure the style needed is standard, i.e. you did not modify it,
you can simply use the following configuration for clang-format package:

(use-package clang-format
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq clang-format-style '"LLVM")) ;; or whatever style you need.


if you have (and need to use) a .clang-format file, then in
above snippet modify the config to the line (setq clang-format-style '"file")

For any of these alternative, use the command M-x clang-format-buffer to get
modifications.
Keep in mind the particularities of Emacs when working in c/c++ - there are
several styles available, gnu/k&r/bsd/stroustrup/whitesmith/ellemtel/linux/python/java/awk/user,
and once a file is opened and the style is recognized, it remains at is it,
and saving is according to style, formatting every time may not be needed,
so you can use formatting only when adapting a file (if you add the package apheleia).
Also, the command M-x clang-format, does not format the buffer, but,
contrary to expectations, format only a selected region.

Thank you so much... Now I just need to figure out the error in our clang-format file. Sorry if I have misunderstood anything in your comments above

Thank you so very much I just got formating on save to work also. Thank you
